# detected if a word in column from Dataframe contains any value that is not Hebrew or English

Tags: python, pandas, hebrew, non-english

**Given**

1. DataFrame contains column df['words']

Need to make sure that there is no word that isn't English or Hebrew & that there is no number in the input :

**for example: wrong words**:

pla!n, *, /, ?, mouna笑, ~,!, adקר, etc..

**for example: good words**:

plan, mountain, ארטיק, ok...

in python alone.
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] and _try something_, then provide a [mcve] with the specific problem you are facing.

Answer (score -1):

"".isalpha() אתה יכול להשתמש ב

you can use "".isalpha()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).